# In firefox (or any other webbrowser) search text while ignoring (e.g.) French accents

Tags: firefox, search, special-characters

I am looking for a way to search web pages using firefox (preferably, but any other browser will do also) in such a way that I can enter a word without accents, and it will find all accented versions of the word also.

For example: I type "hote" in the search field and it finds "hôte", or "supprime" and "supprimé", or "grun" and "grün", etc. . Is there any way this would become possible, including scripting some extensions? So kind of like the -i flag to grep, just for the browser search and accents?

(Of course, an about:config flag flip would be best, mapping non-accented searches to all accented variants. But I'm afraid this won't exist? )

Comment: "Is there any way this would become possible, including scripting some extensions?" - Of course, if you make your own search add-on to do this then it will work.

Comment: I don't think it exists yet, but it would be quite handy indeed. Especially for user-generated content where people might be too lazy to type the accented letters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. In the browser Chrome, typing "hote" in the search field will find "hôte" on the page, and similarly for your other examples.